# Conditionally deleting duplicate files with different extensions with extension priority?

Tags: scripting, delete

I have a large directory of files where there are duplicate filenames but different extensions. What I would like to do is remove the duplicates but have a priority order of which extension gets kept.

So, for example, if I had 4 file types *.aaa, *.bbb *.ccc, *.ddd I would want to only keep *.ddd if there was no other file with this name, keep *.ccc if there was no *.aaa or *.bbb, keep *.bbb if there is no *.aaa and always keep *.aaa.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `zsh`, you could do:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
ext=(aaa bbb ccc ddd) # in order of preference.
files=( *.$^ext(ND^/) )
typeset -A seen=()
for f ($files) if (( seen[\$f:r]++ )) echo rm -f -- $f
```

(remove the `echo` if happy).

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work. I can see lots of "*.aaa" files being deleted. In that example it shouldn't delete any "*.aaa" files as they are the top priority.

Comment: @TimR75, I can't reproduce and I can't see how it could delete `*.aaa` files as they are listed first, so `seen[their-root-name]` can only be 0 at the time they're processed. Only way I can imagine it deleting higher priority ones is if there are extensions that overlap in your actual list of extensions as in `ext=(tar.gz gz)` where `anything.tar.gz` would be included twice.

Comment: Sorry it did work. I was looking in the wrong folder. Really appreciate the help. Thanks.